# Using trees to speed up nearest neighbour search on 3D array with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

Using code adapted from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108869/optimizing-python-distance-calculation-while-accounting-for-periodic-boundary-co) question I can do a brute force NN search on a 3D array taking into account the periodic boundary conditions. The code then returns the index of the nearest neighbour and it does this for all neighbours.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

N = 10000  # Num of objects
# create random point positions
coords = np.random.random((3, N)).transpose()

def NN(point):
    dist = np.abs(np.subtract(coords, point))  # Distance between point and all neighbors xyz values
    dist = np.where(dist > 0.5, dist - 1, dist)  # checking if distance is closer if it wraps around
    return (np.square(dist)).sum(axis=-1).argsort()[1]  # Calc distance and find index of nearest neighbour

# multi threading for speed increase 
pool = ThreadPool(12)
match = pool.map(NN, coords)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

For N ~ 50000 it gets very slow as expected.

I would like to know how I would implement this using trees such as [sklearn.BallTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree) or [scipy.spacial.cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy-spatial-ckdtree) and would like to do this without duplicating the space 8 more times as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917664/nearest-neighbor-search-with-periodic-boundary-conditions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `sklearn.BallTree` nor `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` can be easily modified to handle periodic boundary conditions. Periodic boundaries require a fundamentally different set of assumptions than those used in these implementations.

You should consider using an alternative implementation, such as [periodic_kdtree](https://github.com/patvarilly/periodic_kdtree), though note that this is a (somewhat stale) Python implementation and won't be nearly as fast as the Cython/C++ implementations you mention.